# Render will_paginate links as if requested via html, when requested via ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am trying to update an index page via an ajax call.  The only problem I am having is that the will_paginate links that are returned have the .js extension for the url.

Here is my coffeescript that makes the request.

```
  onSearchBoxChanged : () ->
    console.log "search box changed"
    console.log @view.getSearchBoxContents()
    jQuery.getScript('/users.js?search=' + @view.getSearchBoxContents() )
```

In the users controller I respond to both html and javascript.

```
 respond_to :html, :js
```

I also have a partial for the will_paginate links (in a _paginate.html.erb file)

```
<%= will_paginate %>
```

Here is my index.js.coffee file

```
console.log "back from server "
console.log '<%= escape_javascript(render(@users)) %>'
userList = '<%= escape_javascript(render(@users)) %>'
console.log '<%= escape_javascript(render("paginate")) %>'
paginate =  '<%= escape_javascript(render("paginate")) %>'
jQuery.publish('new_user_list_from_server', [ userList, paginate ] )
```

Here are the links that are printed in the console

```
<div class="pagination"><ul><li class="prev previous_page disabled"><a href="#">&#8592; Previous</a></li> <li class="active"><a rel="start" href="/users.js?_=1413756082270&amp;page=1&amp;search=j">1</a></li> <li><a rel="next" href="/users.js?_=1413756082270&amp;page=2&amp;search=j">2</a></li> <li class="next next_page "><a rel="next" href="/users.js?_=1413756082270&amp;page=2&amp;search=j">Next &#8594;</a></li></ul></div>
```

I could just replace all the /users.js? with /users?, but it seems like there should be a less "hacky" way to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar but not entirely identical problem, which I solved with a custom renderer. It's a bit less hacky, but unfortunately the code I needed to add was in the middle of the super-method so there's no easy way to use "super". This code lives in app/helpers/pagination_helper.rb. It overrides the link method of the renderer with a copy of the original and inserts some new code in the middle, so be aware that it is vulnerable to bugs introduced by revisions to the will_paginate code itself.

```
module PaginationHelper
  class Renderer < WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer
    protected
    def link(text, target, attributes = {})
      if target.is_a? Fixnum
        attributes[:rel] = rel_value(target)
        target = url(target)
      end

      # New code here:
      if @options[:path].present?
        parts = target.split "?"
        parts.shift
        parts.unshift @options[:path]
        target = parts.join "?"
      end
      # End of new code

      attributes[:href] = target
      tag(:a, text, attributes)
    end
  end
end
```

Then in the view specify the custom renderer and override the path:

```
<%= will_paginate @my_models, path: my_models_path, renderer: PaginationHelper::Renderer %>
```